# Not see the inbox messages for the deleted accounts

Tags: discussion, global-inbox

If I had an account on an SE site, deleted it, and then made a new account on the same website, I am going to get the inbox messages from the old account (assuming all of these are created using the same credentials). I am lazy to produce a screenshot but I think moderators must be aware of this.

Is there a way to change this behaviour (i.e. *not* see the messages directed to the old account)? For example, some user may be leaving comments that make me sad (but are not necessarily flag-worthy) and I do not want to see them at all. If not, is it possible to disable inbox totally (so that it does not show flashy red digits which attract your attention)?

Comment: _"If I had an account on an SE site, deleted it, and then made a new account on the same website ..."_ Can you explain what's the reasoning for such action at all please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ well, maybe at some point of time I felt like I do not want to contribute anymore but after a year I have changed my mind.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ when deleting account, it's expected to delete all the associated content or at least have it dis-associated from the deleted account. It happens with posts and comments, so expecting this to apply for inbox messages is totally valid.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is a technical issue that can't be easily fixed or changed.

Unlike posts and comments, inbox items are not site-specific but rather part of your **network profile**. As long as you keep the same network profile, you'll see all inbox items, on all sites.

The only way out is for you to delete your account on **all sites** (one by one), and create a totally new account, better even using a different email.

<s>If you want to keep your other accounts and just delete some inbox messages, we can't delete them ourselves, but SE developers/staff probably can, so in extreme cases we can send "contact us" form asking those items to be deleted.</s>

Worth to mention, that deleting specific inbox messages is [not an option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331050/not-see-the-inbox-messages-for-the-deleted-accounts/331051?noredirect=1#comment1079777_331051).

Comment: but can I disable inbox 100% so that I see nothing (from all sites)?

Comment: I also believe deleting all accounts across the network will not delete the network profile, you need to explicitly contact SE team I think.

Comment: @user571469 no, we can't disable the inbox. We can ignore it of course, but then we'll lose critical information and comments we need to see, so not a good idea IMO.

Comment: @user571469 Deleting all site accounts will generally erase your network profile after 24 hours, unless you've ever manually logged in on stackexchange.com (in which case you'll have to contact SE to get it deleted).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog such a curious behaviour, I wonder if it was intended by the developers.

Comment: We would not ever manually delete inbox items for a user.

Comment: @animuson oh, well, good to know. I thought maybe in really extreme cases this would be possible. Thanks.

Comment: @user571469 see official reply above from SE staff. Edited answer to reflect it.

Comment: @user571469 You'll find several other historical artifacts in lots of places in the system.

Comment: @Sonic it's not about "artifacts", but rather unexpected behavior that makes little sense for those not aware how the system works.